# How to trigger dropdownlist onchange when setting selected from DataController

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, dom-events, querystringparameter

I have an MVC View (https://mydomain/Data/MyChart) that contains a dropdownlist where the onchange event triggers an ajax call to get data to populate a chart.  This is working perfectly.

I now want to add the functionality whereby I could call this view and pass the item to select via a querystring parameter.
https://mydomain/Data/MyChart?station=ChartA

When doing this, I can retrieve the querystring value, and successfully set the item selected in the dropdownlist, however the onchange event does not triggered so the chart is not generated.

What am I missing?

.NET Fiddle to demo selecting dropdown and getting value in change event
https://dotnetfiddle.net/uZi8LU

.NET Fiddle demonstrating setting a value (querystring) to set the selected item and onchange NOT triggered:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/kCJMC4

Answer (score 0):

Your new functionality pre-loads the page with a selected value, so the element it is not *changed* after the document is *ready* (for the pre-loaded value).  The new functionality requires a once-off ajax call immediately once the document is ready:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($("#StationGroup option:selected").text());

            //  StationId Dropdown change function
            $("#StationGroup").change(function () {
                alert($("#StationGroup option:selected").text());
            });         
        });
    </script>
```